# Task Manager CMD.EXE Description

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows batch script which issues the following command:

```
start "%IDT%_%IDTU%" D:\Apps\P_PROC\SNF2.BAT %IDF% %IDT% %IDTU% "%FNAME%" "%PARM%" "%NFNAME%" %PART% "%COMMENT%" %RPART%
```

When I go to Task Manager, the process CMD.EXE always shows a Description of "Windows Command Processor."  If I have many start(s) triggering, how can I  get the title from my start command as the Description in Task Manager?

Comment: What research on this have you done? Have you tried renaming CMD.EXE to see if that affects the view in taskmgr? Have you tried setting the windows title?

Comment: Isn't the title after the start "%IDT%_%IDTU%" ?  I wanted the Task Manager Description to reflect whatever "%IDT%_%IDTU%" evaluates to.

Comment: Add the `title` command on top of your batch script, perhaps that helps...

Comment: I also tried that, but it still not show the TITLE I wanted.  Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"
```

from the command prompt.

Or - use the `applications` tab rather than `processes`

Comment: It seems that a "start ...." creates a cmd.exe in Task Manager, the tasklist just shows Window Title as N/A, and the Applications shows nothing.  I guess I need to rethink how approach it differently instead of using start .....   Thanks for the tasklist command.

Comment: Could you insert `title %1_%2` as a line in `snf2.bat`?

Comment: The title did not work either, but you gave me an idea.  I converted from the START.... to: TITLE ..... and CMD /C ...... # this worked.